# Customer Hierarchy in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a client who wants to setup a customer hierarchy in Shopify.

Essentially customer 1 thru 10 each with unique emails would belong to Company A and all 10 customers could see orders from the company.

Searched everywhere and haven't found any good resources. Any ideas?

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the out of the box features. You may need an app to assign the hierarchy using metafields..

Comment: I've built an app that does this. However, I'm not sure what the rules are regarding self promotion on stack overflow. The app puts customers into groups, and tags an order with the group ID... It's very straight forward to implement.

Comment: @Rob Can you send me details or leave app link here? I'm interested.

Comment: @Damon Its a private app... not available publicly... Is it possible to direct message on here?

Comment: If there is, I couldn't find out how. Could you email me - damon.d.wilson@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0):

Default shopify is not providing this type of feature.

Shopify is hosting base e-commerce solution providers so direct modification is not possible.

You need to create the app for this functionality.

Here is the [admin api](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference) document link with help of that you can develop your app